# fomulario multiusuario

Tags: java, sql, windows-forms, .net

buenas tengo un formulario que usa tablas temporales vb.net , cuando varios usuarios ingresan al formulario utilizan el mismo formulario  y el mismo ID , cada uno llena una  informacion diferente
el problema es cuando doy guardar  se duplica.

lo que quiero es cada usuario pueda usar mismo ID trabajar y llenar la informacion.

Comment: Deberías añadir el código antes de que te cierren la pregunta

Comment: Bienvenido, es demasiado importante agregar lo que trataste o investigaste, modifica tu pregunta en base a [ask], saludos.